# Appending to list during multiprocessing

Tags: python

I want to check if some element is already present in some list, while i am constantly updating that list.I am using multiprocessing to achieve this, but currently my list gets reinitialised every time.Any suggestions on how i could append to the list without it being reinitialized would be very helpful.Thanks in advance.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

import socket

# Set the default timeout in seconds
timeout = 20
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

from PIL import Image 
import hashlib
import os
image_hash_list=[]
url_list =[]
some_dict=dict()
def getImages(val):
    # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    #Dowload images
    f = open('image_files.txt', 'a')
    try:
        url=val # preprocess the url from the input val
        local=url.split('/')[-1] #Filename Generation From Global Varables And Rand Stuffs...
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,local)
        md5hash = hashlib.md5(Image.open(local).tobytes())
        image_hash = md5hash.hexdigest()
        global image_hash_list
        global url_list
        if image_hash not in image_hash_list:
            image_hash_list.append(image_hash)
            some_dict[image_hash] = 0
            os.remove(local)
            f.write(url+'\n')
            return 1
        else:
            os.remove(local)
        print(some_dict.keys())
    except Exception as e:
        return 0

# if __name__ == '__main__':
files = "Identity.txt"
lst = list(open(files))
lst = [l.replace("\n", "") for l in lst]
pool = mp.Pool(processes=12)
res = pool.map(getImages, lst)
print ("tempw")
```

Here the image_hash_list get reinitialised every time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Manager` to create shared lists and dicts (and other types too): [Sharing state betweek processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).